# Xpath starting retuning None on Scrapy

Tags: dom, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a site and to do so, I'm using Scrapy. So, when doing requests to nested pages, the procedure usually gets the the information correctly on the first trials, but, on later requests the nodes starts to return None. I'm using xpath's functionality. Below I'm pasting some lines of the parse function:

(I tried this one with the approach of explicitly comparing the class value)

```
title = response.xpath('//span[@class="inlineFree"]/text()').extract_first()
```

(With this one I used the contains function)

```
view = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"count")]/text()').extract_first()
```

(I've also used this one when I found more suitable)

```
comments = response.css('div.commentMessage > span::text').extract()
```

Am I doing something wrong on paths?
Is there any reason for the crawler to stop reading the nodes correctly?

Comment: Please show your output log or your spider's code

Comment: ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph5b4d80f6bc990> (referer: https://www.pornhub.com/video?c=1&page=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grad/si/16/guilherme.hra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
    view = int(response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "count")]/text()').extract_first().replace(',',''))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

@gangabass

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say what the problem is without the log messages or the spider code but..
What happens most of the time is that websites fo not follow a strict html structure .For some properties the 'title' may be inside the span 
but for the next iteration it may be 
span[@class="inlineFree"]/h1/text() or

or any other tag
so you should check the html for those returning None